# prove that a function is a diffeomorphism

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

anyone can help me to prove that $f(\alpha,x,y,z) = (\sinh(\alpha) x, \sinh(\alpha)y,\cosh(\alpha)z)$ is a diffeomorphism? In fact, i'm not sure if it's a diffeomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

At every point $p$, the derivative is a linear map $df_p:\mathbb{R}^4\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$. Such a map can never be invertible for dimension reasons. So your function is not a diffeomorphism, not even local. Of course, it is not even a homeomorphism, due to the [invariance of domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain). Not even local again.

Comment: Of course. Now I saw my mistake. Thank You.

Comment: In fact, I wanted prove that a Prolate spheroidal coordinates is a diffeomorphism.

Comment: @jonjones  That's a different question. So you should ask another question, I think.